# Displaying data from AJAX call to database with jquery and CI

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

The model seems to be working as well as the controller. The AJAX displays the results as "null" so I think it is because we need to send the data as json. Any ideas on how to get the data into the correct format and to display in the view

View

```
 <button type='button' name='getdata' id='getdata'>Get Data.</button>

 <div id='result_table' style="color:white;">
 hola amigo
 </div>

<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
$('#getdata').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/trial/getValues';?>',
                         type:'POST',
                         dataType: 'json',
                          error: function(){
                          $('#result_table').append('<p>goodbye world</p>');
                          },
                         success: function(results){

                          $('#result_table').append('<p>hello world</p>');

                          } // End of success function of ajax form
                          }); // End of ajax call

                });
</script>
```

Controller

```
function getValues(){
    $this->load->model('get_db');
    $data['results'] = $this->get_db->getAll();
    return $data;
}
```

Model

```
class Get_db extends CI_Model{
    function getAll(){
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM questions");
        return $query->result();
        //returns from this string in the db, converts it into an array
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your view, you set your data type to json so you need a controller that it's generate a json output. codeIgniter has a system to generate this type. you can use this code in your **controller** to do that:

```
$this->load->model('get_db');
$data = $this->get_db->getAll();

$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode( $data ));
```

and in **ajax success** get your response and use it:

```
success: function(response){
   server_res = JSON.parse(response);
   console.log(server_res);

   $('#result_table').append('<p>hello world</p>');
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have entered the code as you have typed it and I am still not getting a response from the db.

Comment: to generate an json to response your AJAX request you need to generate an packet with `application/json` header. in your ajax success please console.log(response) and write output for me.

Answer (score 0):

just print/echo the `$data` in controller if you want html form(dont return). If you want json then print/echo [json_encode($array)](http://php.net/json_encode)

and in success ajax write

```
success: function(results){
     $('#result_table').append(results.arraykey);//arraykey=array key from controller
} // End
```

Comment: yah you are getting json from controller which makes it [object Object]. also qID,email,qText .. are the arraykey. write append(results.email) and see waht happens. Youa re on right track

Answer (score 0):

In the controller just use this

```
function getValues(){
    $this->load->model('get_db');
    echo json_encode($this->get_db->getAll());
}
```

And in the view

```
success: function(results){
   results = JSON.parse(results);
   $('#result_table').append('<p>hello world</p>');
}
```